# Не могу получить данные из csv файла python 3.5: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, unicode

Собственно код:

```
csvfile = open("pr.csv", mode="r")
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
for row in spamreader:
    print(row)
```

Содержание файла:

> абв
>   fffff
>   выфвфыв

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/parserwordstat/123.py", line 10, in <module>
    for row in spamreader:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

использовал команду

```
open("pr.csv", encoding="utf-8").read()
```

все также выдает:

> UnicodeDecodeError

содержание самого файла:

```
print(open("pr.csv", "rb").read())
```

> b'\xe0\xe1\xe2\r\nfffff\r\n\xe2\xfb\xf4\xe2\xf4\xfb\xe2\r\n'

Comment: @jfs `UnicodeDecodeError` остается
вот что выдает код, что вы дали: `b'\xe0\xe1\xe2\r\nfffff\r\n\xe2\xfb\xf4\xe2\xf4\xfb\xe2\r\n'`
в общих чертах имею представление о кодировках.

Comment: @jfs все понял, оформил как надо, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл закодирован, используя cp1251 кодировку, а не utf-8:

```
>>> b'\xe0\xe1\xe2\r\nfffff\r\n'.decode("cp1251")
'абв\r\nfffff\r\n'
```

Вы вероятно пытаетесь открыть файл, созданный на русской Винде (где ANSI codepage это cp1251),  в Unix, где utf-8 часто используется для `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` —кодировка текста, используемая по умолчанию при открытии файлов с помощью `open()`.

Чтобы прочитать csv файл, передайте нужную кодировку явно:

```
with open("pr.csv", encoding="cp1251", newline='') as file:
    ...
```